# Mysql fetch ressults and current rank

Tags: php, mysql

> =What's the best way of doing this? I'm pulling back 100 records ordered by score for a high score list. I also need to pull back the users rank and points to the next position.

I'm currently doing it like so but I'm not sure it's the best way of doing it

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM highScores ORDER BY score DESC");
```

I'm looping through those results to show the top scores. Then to get the users rank and next points I'm doing the following

```
$rank = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT id, score FROM highScores WHERE score>='$userScore'"));
```

That gets me the rank and then I do another query for the next position above the user and fetch that score

```
$next_rank_score = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT score FROM highScores ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT " . ($rank-2) . ",1"));
```

There has to be a much better way to do this but I can't think of one.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are doing works, you don't necessarily have to change it.  Good to get ideas though, good that you asked.

Here is an approach requiring only one hit on the database.  Also, limiting the number of records returned will buy speed, especially if you have lots of scores to pick the top 10 from.

```
    <?php

$query = 'SELECT * FROM highScores ORDER BY score DESC limit 0, 101';
$highScores = mysql_query($query);
$ranks = array();
$scores = array();
$score_to_nexts = array();
$i=1;
while ($highScore = mysql_fetch_array($highScores) and $i<102):
    $ranks[$i] = $i;
    $scores[$i] = $highScore['score'];
    if ($i !== 1):
        $score_to_nexts[$i-1] = strval($scores[$i-1] - $scores[$i])
    endif;
    $i++;
endwhile;

$i=1;
while ($i<11):
    $rank   = $ranks[$i];
    $scores = $scores[$i];
    $score_to_next = $score_to_nexts[$i];
    $i++;
endwhile;
?>
```

php rips through arrays with blinding speed, so this definitely would be close to as fast as it can be done.  There might be some logic for squeezing down the cycles, but since your arrays only have to handle 11 members, I'd run with this.

A problem with the routine you have is scores can change between DB reads, so your numbers could not add up right.  By running the scores off one DB read, everything is going to be in sync.

Regarding time for DB reads, it used to be that running extra DB reads was a big no-no, but now-days, that doesn't matter nearly as much.  The webserver will load parts of the DB into memory, making DB reads often as fast as php-only in-memory operations.  Exception would be if you are running a lot of data or getting a ton of traffic and need to conserve resources.

Comment: Awesome going to digest this now. The main reason for this is I'm making too many calls to the database and I was looking to limit that. Putting more strain on the php side isn't an issue at all

Comment: Okay I found an issue with doing it that way. If the users score isn't in the top 11 scores then there is no way to get the points to next rank. For example say I'm in 20th place and I view the high scores I can't see how many points I need to gain to get into 19th place

Comment: Thanks for posting the problem.  I changed the code to list the top 100 scores.